# disabling next.js server side rendering to prevent window is undefined errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a private NPM package that I maintain, which I use in a Next.js project. Both projects are React, Typescript projects.

I've recently added a graph into the NPM project and have now run into the problem of; all the calls to window within that NPM package throw an error `window is undefined` within the Next.js project

As I'm using a library, that I don't have control over, to build my graph, I don't have the luxury of wrapping the calls to window in some sort of `if (typeof window !== "undefined")` statement.

I get these errors on build of my Next.js project, before I've even made a call to a component that makes use of the graphing library. Simply including my NPM package in my main project results in these errors arising.

Would it be possible to stop server-side rendering just for that particular graphing library or perhaps my entire NPM package?

Alternatively any other solution would be welcome, however wild.

Comment: Could you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: How is there no simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the constrain you mentioned. I don't think there are much options. You simply don't have `window` object in `node` environment.

You can render other parts of the page where SSR is possible. and you can dynamically render with `ssr: false` for the portion where you cannot SSR due to `window` object.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

// wrap your component that uses the graph lib.
const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/myGraphComponent'),
  { ssr: false }
)

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
      <p>HOME PAGE is here!</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Reference:

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr

Comment: The problem I'm running into is I get the window is undefined error before I've even called or imported the component. Just my NPM package being installed is enough for it to throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try dynamic import your graph import